# smallest value of hash() function?

Tags: python, c, hash, python-3.x, 32bit-64bit

in python (3), what is the smallest value that `hash(x)` can return?

i want to use hashes to give a quick 'fingerprint' to database values (basically making it easy to see whether two longish, similar texts are actually equal or not), and want to get rid of negative numbers (for simplicity), so i thought i'd just add the smallest possible value to obtain values of zero and up. [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hash) is very helpfully stating "Hash values are integers." which is about as much as i knew before.

i was a bit surprised today when i found that my hand-compiled python on a 64bit ubuntu apparently uses 64 bits or so for its hashing function; i have always thought that should be 32bit. does machine architecture have an impact on the `hash()` function?

also, when i compiled python, i did not set any option to compile for a 64bit architecture (hoping it would "just work"). does python adjust that by itself or do i now have a 32bit python on a 64bit machine? not a silly question i believe as many times you are offered separate packages depending on the processer.

**edit**: i strongly suspect the answer will be closely related to `sys.maxint` which has been sadly removed from python 3. my suspicion is that i should `def xhash( x ): return hash( x ) - ( -maxint - 1 )` if `maxint` was available. i know this value 'lost its value' due to the unification of ints and longs, but here might be one area where it could still prove useful. anybody have an idea how to implement an analogue?

Comment: Even lacking `maxint`, you're probably happy to assume that the hash occupies some underlying integer type on the platform. If you just want to figure out whether it's 32 bits or 64, then take the hash of any old thing (well, not the integer 0) and look at the order of magnitude of the answer. Assuming a good hash function, the possibility that the first 32 binary digits of the hash are *all* 0 is negligible, so that one hash value will tell you the range. Alternatively, sacrifice 1 bit of hash quality, and just use `abs(hash(x))`.

Answer (score 5):

`hash()` can return any integer, and as you have seen, the size of the integer can vary with the architecture.  This is one of the reasons dictionary ordering is arbitrary: the same set of operations on two different platforms can give different results because the hashes used along the way can differ.

If all you are doing is showing a hash for a quick fingerprint, then simply keep a subset of the bits.  It's still valid as a hash.  The only requirement of a hash function is that equal values must have equal hashes.  After that, differences among hashes simply affect the efficiency of the algorithms using the hash, because the chances of collision go up or down.

So for example, you could decide you want an 8-digit hash, and get it by using:

```
hash(x) % 100000000
```

Or you could get an eight-character alphanumeric hash to display with:

```
md5(hash(x)).hexdigest()[:8]
```

Comment: If `hash` can return negative values, then `hash(x) % 100000000` can be negative. I quickly looked for an operation `%%` that would satisfy the equation x = (x // y) * y + x %% y but I didn't find it. Does it exist in Python?

Comment: I think you'll find that the Python % operator does what you want.  The 2.6 docs claim it satisfies x == (x/y)*y + (x%y).  If you find that negative numbers are creeping in, though, you can use abs(hash(x)) % 10000000

Answer (score 4):

hash functions usually use the full range of the return value.  The reason is that they usually are constructed with bit operations (shifting, xoring, etc) -- the bits in the return value are all used during the algorithm.

Why are positive values easier or harder than negative ones?

Comment: this is only a typographic issue; i want nothing more than get rid of the minus sign. and, yes, negative numbers are harder than positive ones, which is why they got found/invented so much later in history. but my concern is more typographic.

Comment: i do present them in hex, but of course they retain the minus sign then

Comment: just FYI, Python by convention never returns `-1` as a hash value (it signifies an error condition in the C code).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question should be:

```
assert(hash(100) == 100 and hash(-100) == -100)
smallest_hash_value= -2**min(range(256), key=lambda i: hash(-2**i))
```

This depends on the fact that Python uses the integer itself as a hash (with the exception of `-1`) iff the integer is a valid `hash()` result. The algorithm normally should remain the same whatever the architecture.

Comment: i do not seem to grasp what you intend to say with `-2**min(range(256), key=lambda i: hash(-2**i))`; care to explain?

Comment: @flow: this evaluates to the smallest `hash()` result that could be produced by your installation of Python.

Comment: oh wah, took me a little but now i get it. the `256` could really be any number greater than the greatest expected word size, right?

Comment: @flow: exactly; I was just being over-cautious and wanted my answer's validity to last for at least five years :)

Answer (score 1):

so today i was luckier at the google casino, and this is what i found:

(1) **system architecture** whether a given python is running on a 64 or a 32bit machine can be found by

```
from platform import architecture
print( architecture() )
```

from the documentation: "Queries the given executable (defaults to the Python interpreter binary) for various architecture information. Returns a tuple (bits, linkage) which contain information about the bit architecture and the linkage format used for the executable. Both values are returned as strings." on my machine, that's `('64bit', 'ELF')`. bingo.

(2) **smallest integer** there is no `sys.maxint` in python 3 no more, but there is `sys.maxsize`. the docs say "An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type `Py_ssize_t` can take. It’s usually `2**31 - 1` on a 32-bit platform and `2**63 - 1` on a 64-bit platform." therefore,

```
from sys import maxsize
assert maxsize == 2**63 - 1
```

works on my machine.

(3) to directly answer the original question: "the smallest value of the `hash()` function *should* be minus whatever `sys.maxsize` reports. for this reason, it can be expected that

```
def xhash( x ): return hash( x ) + sys.maxsize + 1
```

will only ever report values ≥ 0."